# What happens when a horse steps in a hole while running?

Tags: horses

The good guy (GG) in my story is trying to make the bad guy (BG) ride his horse off a cliff.

GG has prepared the ground ahead of time by digging a series of holes (each one the size of a gopher hole) near the edge of the cliff. BG's horse starts running towards the cliff... but I highly doubt that any horse would voluntarily jump off just because its master wasn't paying attention. So, I decided to introduce the holes. The horse will twist its "ankle" and topple over.

But what exactly happens when a horse steps in a hole while running at top speed? Does it hit the ground head first? Does it crumple and then roll? Does it buck?

When I search online, I can only find articles that warn against riding too quickly through fields with gopher holes, as "serious injury" may occur.

Any further detail would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: [Why do they shoot horses with broken legs?](https://www.theweek.co.uk/62872/why-do-they-shoot-horses-with-broken-legs)

Answer (score 2):

It would be extremely foolish, implausibly so for a horseman of any experience, to ride fast towards a cliff edge on unknown terrain. Holes in the ground occur naturally. There is thus a natural risk of the horse falling, and the rider going over the cliff.

Ordinary sensible horsemanship will prevent your antagonist falling into this trap. You need a different trap.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bad guy has absolutely no problems to ride until the very bottom of a cliff (which is in itself dangerous to a human due to risk of the edge giving in, let alone one mounted on a horse and thus much heavier), after a short search, apparently stepping into a rodent hole for a horse can cause injuries from an injured tendon to a broken leg. In the latter, assuming it's the front leg, it'll likely tend to fall diagonally, in the direction to the broken leg, so if the cliff is at his left, you "want" the horse to step into a hole with its left forelimb (though personally I'm mostly sure that just luring the bad guy to a place in which he's alone and shooting him in the head would be much easier, faster and better both for you and BG's horse).